# strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
kpi_workbook = pd.read_excel(r'D:\Maintenance\Bloc 6\PROJECT KPI\COPIL\test.xlsx', sheet_name="Sheet1")
i=1

for c in kpi_workbook["date"]:
    date_time_object= datetime.strptime(c , '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    data_type = type(c)
    if data_type == str:
       kpi_workbook.cell(row=1+i, column=2).value = date_time_object.strftime('%x %X')
       kpi_workbook.save(r'D:\Maintenance\Bloc 6\PROJECT KPI\COPIL\test.xlsx', sheet_name="Sheet1")
       i=i+1
       print(date_time_object)
    else:
        kpi_workbook.cell(row=1+i, column=2).value = date_time_object.strftime('%x %X')
        kpi_workbook.save(r'D:\Maintenance\Bloc 6\PROJECT KPI\COPIL\test.xlsx', sheet_name="Sheet1")
        i=i+1
        print(c)
```

the program pulls from excel dates that may be a string or datetime on excel and print each cell on the cell next to it to make sure it maintains the original sequence of dates on excel.

the program ran just fine till I added the code that prints and saves back to excel
here is the error I get when i run the code :

```
 File "d:\Maintenance\Bloc 6\PROJECT KPI\COPIL\Source code\KPI_convert sting to datetime.py", line 7, in <module>
    date_time_object= datetime.strptime(c , '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime
```

Comment: `read_excel()` is already parsing the date, so you don't need to call `strptime()`.

Answer (score 0):

stack overflow site too almost 2 days to approve my question so I had to look elsewhere. I already fixed this issue, below you can find my final code, tested and it works perfectly.

```
  from datetime import datetime
    import pandas as pd
    from datetime import date
    
    todays_date = pd.to_datetime(date.today())
    
    kpi_workbook=pd.read_excel(r'D:\Maintenance\Bloc 6\PROJECT KPI\COPIL\Extraction_DI.xlsx')
    kpi_workbook=pd.read_excel(r'D:\Maintenance\Bloc 6\PROJECT KPI\COPIL\Extraction_OT.xlsx')
    
    kpi_workbook['Date création DI'] = pd.to_datetime(kpi_workbook['Date création DI'])
    kpi_workbook['Anné'] = kpi_workbook['Date création DI'].dt.year
    kpi_workbook['Moi'] = kpi_workbook['Date création DI'].dt.month
    kpi_workbook['Jour'] = kpi_workbook['Date création DI'].dt.day
    backlog_age= todays_date - kpi_workbook['Date création DI']
    
    for index, row in kpi_workbook.iterrows():
        if backlog_age[index] < pd.Timedelta('90 days'):
           kpi_workbook.at[index, 'Backlog Age'] = 'Backlog < 3 Mois'
           print('Backlog < 3 Mois')
        elif backlog_age[index] > pd.Timedelta('180 days'):
             kpi_workbook.at[index, 'Backlog Age'] = 'Backlog > 6 Mois'
             print('Backlog > 6 Mois') 
        else:
           backlog_age[index] > pd.Timedelta('30 days') and backlog_age[index] < pd.Timedelta('180 days')
           kpi_workbook.at[index, 'Backlog Age'] = '3 Mois < Backlog < 6 Mois'
           print('3 Mois < Backlog < 6 Mois')
    
    selected_columns = ['Date création DI', 'Anné', 'Moi', 'Jour', 'Backlog Age']
    kpi_workbook[selected_columns].to_excel(r'D:\Maintenance\Bloc 6\PROJECT KPI\COPIL\fin.xlsx')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).